# Tropical convolution with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Background: I am writing a package that requires something quite akin to array convolution. (Tropical Convolution is also called min-plus convolution). The Wikipedia article isn't great, but it's here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_calculus#Min-plus_algebra

Basically, if d=mpConv(a,b), then d[c]=max(a[j]+b[c-j]).
Standard convolution would be d[c]=sum(a[j]*b[c-j]).

I have two numpy.arrays a and b and the output range should be r. So, here's what I have right now:

```
def mpConv(a,b,r):
    A = len(a) - 1
    B = len(b) - 1
    return [numpy.amax(a[max(0,c-B)  :min(c,A)+1    :+1]+
                       b[min(c-B,0)-1:max(0,c-A)-B-2:-1],0) for c in r]
```

This runs as desired. I haven't dealt with numpy before, so I am wondering about efficiency, speed, and just general ways to use numpy better.

Is there a more efficient way to loop over the range r? (It's always going to be of the form r=numpy.arange(s,e) if that matters.)

Is this the "numpy way of doing things?"

The numpy.convolve routine is written in C, so the source code isn't too helpful for this. I suppose I could write this in C, but I would lose the power and ease of python.

Bonus info:
The fastest way I'm awate of is here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4771 (Necklaces, Convolutions, and X+Y by Bremner, Chan, Demaine, Erickson, Hurtado, Iacono, Langerman, Patrascu, Taslakian)
I'm not too worried about doing that. I would probably implement it in C first. I don't believe I will gain a significant speed boost from non-naive methods.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone happens to need this ever, here's what I feel is nicest after some digging:

This function computes the addition of all needed pairs and puts them into an array.

```
import numpy
def plus_convolve(a, b, e=0):
    if len(a)<len(b):
        return plus_convolve(b,a,e)
    return numpy.concatenate((                    #This is for padding (as stated below)
        numpy.add(a,b[:,None]),                   #Do the desired outer addition. Broadcasting handles this well.
        numpy.broadcast_to(e,(len(b),)+b.shape)   #Pad the end of the result with, e, the fill value.
        ),1).ravel()[:-b.size].reshape(           #We reshape the array to have one fewer row. This makes the convolution line up exactly like we want
            (len(b),len(a)+len(b)-1)+b.shape[1:]  #This is the new size
        )
```

We can simply compute the max of each row to get the max-plus convolution (in this example, I'm convolving a 1000x10 matrix with a 2000x10 matrix.)

```
a=numpy.random.randint(0,20,(1000,10))
b=numpy.random.randint(0,20,(2000,10))
numpy.amax(plus_convolve(a,b),0)
```

I believe this is faster since it pushes all the work onto numpy, but it uses more memory. My original is pretty good if memory is an issue.

I suppose the question was too esoteric for SO, but if anyone happens to need this, post a comment: I'd be curious why.